# Find unused classes or dead code in Haxe project

Tags: haxe

Somebody know a way to automatically get a list of unused classes in Haxe project? 
I not find documentation about that, but the information should be available somewhere. Like a diff after dead code elimination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I mix two solutions to get a full answer.

- The first one is a diff between Haxe files in source path and parsed classes in verbose mode compilation.
- The seconds one is a diff with `dce-debug` and files in source path. thx @jonasmalacofilho

You can find my script on gist : https://gist.github.com/aliokan/0a9abded7c079ad0260f651245964db2

Answer (score 3):

You can get a DCE log by compiling with `-D dce-debug`.  ([relevant entry in the manual](https://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage-flags.html))

For example, compiling a `class Hello { static function main() trace("Hello!"); }` with `haxe --interp -main Hello -D dce-debug` yields something like:

```
...
[DCE] Removed field Type.getClass
[DCE] Removed field Type.getEnum
[DCE] Removed field Type.getSuperClass
[DCE] Removed field Type.getClassName
[DCE] Removed field Type.getEnumName
[DCE] Removed field Type.resolveClass
[DCE] Removed field Type.resolveEnum
[DCE] Removed field Type.createInstance
[DCE] Removed field Type.createEmptyInstance
[DCE] Removed field Type.createEnum
[DCE] Removed field Type.createEnumIndex
[DCE] Removed field Type.getInstanceFields
[DCE] Removed field Type.getClassFields
[DCE] Removed field Type.getEnumConstructs
[DCE] Removed field Type.typeof
[DCE] Removed field Type.enumEq
[DCE] Removed field Type.enumConstructor
[DCE] Removed field Type.enumParameters
[DCE] Removed field Type.enumIndex
[DCE] Removed field Type.allEnums
[DCE] Removed class Type
[DCE] Removed enum ValueType
...
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but `-D dce-debug` return logs on field level, not class. I will used `-D dump=pretty` and make a diff between sources and dump files list.

Comment: That makes sense (since DCE obviously has to work on fields), but it's too bad. : /  Anyway, diffing the AST dumps would be my plan B too...

Comment: Actually, `-D dce-debug` does also output removed classes and other types: `[DCE] Removed class haxe.io.Bytes`.  Can't you filter those lines with `grep` (Unix/Linux/Mac) or `find` (Windows)?

Comment: After investigation, `dce-debug` provide only a part of the answer. Because DCE analyse only code use in the project. If you don't have reference to a class in your project (from Main class), it is not listed in DCE logs.